# c++ pipelining commands with execv and input redirection

Tags: c++, posix, exec, pipe, io-redirection

Trying to write a shell that processes internal and external commands. I can get the internal commands and one external at a time.

My question is how to get a command like this to run: "ls -l | grep lib | wc -l"

I'm using a fork(), and passing external commands through execv() in a char*[].

Any thoughts on how to work this? I assume using pipe() or something, but I'm not sure.

Second part of the question: how about dealing with i/o redirection? Can anyone point me to somewhere helpful?

**EDIT**
So far, @Alex W is my hero. However, since I'm new to the pipe() and dup2() commands, I'm a little hesitant on what each call and variable are for.

Here's the code I have that handles a single external command (Example = "ls -l -a"):

```
    pid_t pid;
    pid = fork();
    if (pid < 0)
    {
        cout << "Fork failed." << endl;
    }
    else if (pid == 0)
    {
        execvp(exec_args[0], exec_args);   //exec_args is a char*[] where 
        _exit (EXIT_FAILURE);              //exec_args[0] contains "/bin/ls"
    }                                          //[1]="ls" and [2]="-l" [3]="-a"
    else
    {
        int status;
        waitpid(pid, &status, 0);
    }
    break;
```

Comment: The way you suggest is exactly how I would do it.  (By the way, you might tag your question "posix," since it doesn't apply to Windows programmers -- even if you have to remove one of your other tags to do it.)

Comment: I added posix to my tags. Basically I'm looking for some insight as to how "pipe()" works

Comment: I see.  Try `man 7 pipe`.  (Section 7 of the manual, as you probably know, is where system concepts are documented.)

Comment: I found out that i got most of this commands on my windows machine when i installed msysgit and added in PATH. It is way better than PowerShell. You can check there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do use `pipe` and in POSIX systems a pipe works in a similar manner to a file.  You can write to a pipe and read from a pipe, but if there is nothing in the pipe it blocks.  The best place to find information on Unix system calls is the man page for the system call.  On a Unix system you would type `man pipe` into a terminal.  If you don't have access to a Unix terminal then just google "man pipe".  The nice thing about the man pages is they tell you what libraries to include for the given system call.  Make sure you remember that when using any `exec` type system call you are loading a completely new process into that memory and the process that you were executing will stop dead in its tracks.

To use it do something like this:

```
int main()
{
    int id[2];
    int fd[2];
    int fd2[2];
    int fd3[2];
    FILE file;
    int status;
    int sz = 0;
    char buff[1000];
    char buff2[1000];
    string launch[2];
    FILE *fp;

    launch[0] = "./anotherProgramToExecute";
    launch[1] = "./yetAnotherProgram";

    pipe(fd);
    pipe(fd2);
    pipe(fd3);

    for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        id[i] = fork();

        if (id[i] == -1) /* an error occurred */
        {
            perror("Fork failed.\n");
        }
        else if (id[i] == 0) /* this is the child process currently acting */
        {
            if(i == 0)
            {
                dup2(fd[1],1);
            }
            else if(i == 1)
            {
                dup2(fd2[0],0);
                dup2(fd3[1],1);
            }
            execlp(launch[i],launch[i], NULL);
        }
        else /* this is the parent process currently acting */
        {
            sz = read(fd[0], buff, 1000);
            buff[sz] = '\0';
            printf("buff = %s\n",buff);

            close(fd[0]);

            write(fd2[1],buff, 1000);

            read(fd3[0],buff2,1000);

            fp = fopen("bin.txt","w");
            if(fp == NULL)
                printf("Cannot open file.\n");
            else
            {
                fprintf(fp,buff2);
                fclose(fp);
            }

            //printf("Creation of Child Process #%d succeeded!\n",id[i]);
            while(waitpid(id[i], &status, WNOHANG) == 0)
                sleep(0.3);
            if (WIFEXITED(status))
            { 
                // successfully terminated children
            }
            else
            {
                perror("Child has not terminated correctly.\n");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: so helpful, but could you by chance comment some of the variables so I know what each is doing? Like I said, I'm a pipe() noob

Comment: When you call pipe(fd) it is populating the int fd[2] array with two file descriptors. At index 0 it will place the read file descriptor and at index 1 aka fd[1] it will place the write file descriptor. You can use these to read and write to the pipe just like it is a regular file.

Answer (score 0):

The best on-line tutorial I have seen regarding pipes and such is an oldie but a goodie:  http://beej.us/guide/bgipc/.  You might browse it.  One suspects that you'll like it.