# Launch process "executable1 | executable2 | ..." in C, using EXECV

Tags: c++, c, fork, exec

My teacher told me to make a C/C++ program, which will be tested on a Linux Operating System (so it is not necessary this program to work on Windows). This program should get some strings (s1, s2 ... sk) from `argv` and launch the process: `s1 | s2 | ... | sk` (s1, s2 ... sk are executable files).

I tried to make this program as follows, which concats the data from `argv` with `|` after each executable name and then using `system` function to launch the process:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int i = 0, lenght = 0;
    for(i=1; i<argc; i++) {
        lenght += strlen(argv[i]);
    }
    lenght += 3*(argc-2);
    char final_comm[lenght];
    strcpy(final_comm, "");
    for(i=1; i<argc; i++) {
        strcat(final_comm, argv[i]);
        if(i != argc-1)
            strcat(final_comm, " | ");
    }
    printf("%s", final_comm);
    system(final_comm);
    return 0;
}
```

But the teacher said I should to use `execv` function instead of `system`, but I don't know how to launch `s1 | s2 | ... | sn` using `execv`. I tried to use `execv` but I only know at this moment how to launch a process only, with one executable:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char *args[1];
    args[0] = NULL;

        switch(fork()) {
            case -1:
                perror("fork()");
            break;
            case 0:
                execv("executable", args);
            break;
        }

    return 0;
}
```

But I really don't know and I didn't find how to launch a process like `exec1 | exec2 | exec3`.

Comment: You're supposed to *pipe* the standard output of `exec_i` to `exec_i+1`. Both of which you `execv` after `fork`ing.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10873949/c-pipelining-commands-with-execv-and-input-redirection

Comment: Thank you very much! I am trying to do this just now :) Thank you!